# Python client library for Fusion Tables: Running oauth_example.py answers "No module named authorization.oauth"

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-fusion-tables

i've installed python client library for Fusion Tables ([here](http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables-client-python/)) with all dependencies. But if i try to run [oauth_example.py](http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables-client-python/source/browse/trunk/src/samples/oauth_example.py), it aswers me

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./oauth_example.py", line
>   13, in 
>       from authorization.oauth import OAuth ImportError: No module named authorization.oauth

my python version is 2.7.2+ running on Ubuntu 11.10
and yolk -l

> oauth2          - 1.5.211      - active development (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2-1.5.211-py2.7.egg)

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are running the script from the src/samples directory.  Try copying the script up one directory and run from the src directory where it can find the authorization/oauth.py module.  Or you could include something like this in the top of your python script:

```
import sys
sys.path.append( '/home/src/python_modules/fusion-tables-client/src')
```